# Repeat a string n times in elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to make a string of a defined length. In ruby, I would use:

`str = 'a' * 5`

How do I accomplish the same thing in elixir?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use [`String.duplicate/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#duplicate/2):

```
iex(1)> str = String.duplicate("a", 5)
"aaaaa"
```

Comment: You might want to make the example code closer to his question @dogbert: `str = String.duplicate("a",256)`  :)

Comment: Also you might want to make an example less close to the OP but more readable on tablets: `String.duplicate("a", 5)` :)

Comment: @mudasobwa yeah I think that would be better. :)

Comment: Changed mine to match :)

Comment: Even better suggestion @mudasobwa!